# Best practice in a multiple post REST

Tags: angularjs, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Well, guys I work in a project with `Rails/angular` and i have a `has many` relation with two models.

Now I need to do a `multiple post` on `create` action, so I need to know what is the best practice to do this, I read about this and say "post a collection of object", but i think about that and for me isn't a best practice.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to merge both the models data and send a single request and process them in server side code. That will reduce http request. you can merge model objects like

```
var object = angular.extend({}, object1, object2);
```